# Start H2 database programmatically

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm coding a server-client application in Java and I need to implement a local database on the server side and I decided to go for H2 database engine.

One more thing to add is that I usa TCP connection to start and run the database.
This is what I put together so far:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");  
Server server = Server.createTcpServer(DB_PATH).start();

Connection currentConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Where the connection string is `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test`.

That piece of code returns with an exception:

```
Feature not supported: "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" [50100-176]
```

I followed [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/presentation-and-use-h2).

Comment: The article that you linked is sadly not working anymore :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
Server server = null;
            try {
                server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
                Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.
                    getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/stackoverflow", "sa", "");
                System.out.println("Connection Established: "
                        + conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName() + "/" + conn.getCatalog());
             
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the output is Connection Established: H2/STACKOVERFLOW

This has been tested with h2-1.4.184

Answer (score 7):

This is my simple H2-DBManager - just name its filename DBManager.java and feel free to reuse it:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.h2.tools.Server;

public class DBManager {

    private static void startDB() throws SQLException {
        Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "9092", "-tcpAllowOthers").start();

    }

    private static void stopDB() throws SQLException {
        Server.shutdownTcpServer("tcp://localhost:9092", "", true, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

            if (args.length > 0) {
                if (args[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                    startDB();
                }

                if (args[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                    stopDB();
                }
            } else {
                System.err
                        .println("Please provide one of following arguments: \n\t\tstart\n\t\tstop");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to do it a little more easily accepting the defaults:

```
      Server server =  Server.createTcpServer().start();
```