# Embed H2 Database into ETL Application?

Tags: java, h2, talend

I am looking for a way to programmatically start the H2 database service through java / command task.

For Windows: I can use the below command to start the service

```
java -jar C:/H2/h2/bin/h2-1.4.195.jar -tcpAllowOthers
```

From Java App, as described here: [Start H2 database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183503/start-h2-database-programmatically)

Note: I utlizied the simple H2-DBManager Approach.

In both the cases, I see applications keep on running.

My expectation is: I need a way to start the H2 database programmatically and make it in run as a background process and move to the next step.

Also, I am looking for a way to embed postgres database into my ETL application and start it programmatically.

Comment: Only one question per question. Doing this for H2 will be very different then doing this for Postgres (which is not available as an "embedded" database)

Comment: H2 is the high priority .

Comment: So, you found the code and the command. You know what you want. What is your question?

Comment: My question is once I triggered the start the h2 database using command or through java, I am expecting the database service to up in background.

Suppose if I trigger the command through command prompt , it remains at the same command like image : https://ibb.co/nifAQF.

It should run background and allow us to type other commands in the same windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the command line on Windows, try adding an START at the beginning of the command:

`START "" java -jar C:/H2/h2/bin/h2-1.4.195.jar -tcpAllowOthers`

On Linux add an &

`java -jar C:/H2/h2/bin/h2-1.4.195.jar -tcpAllowOthers &`

Comment: How to start H2 database programmatically and once triggered the start command and it need to switch to next step . 


It should not hang there ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand this. What hangs?

Comment: Hangs means the java program remanis in the execution state  like shown in the image https://ibb.co/cOZ3fF.

Once execute , I want this java program to go for completion state..

Comment: Ok, this is a different requirement. So you want to start it in the background, let it run *and end the background h2 process with your ending ETL job*. I am not sure if the solution I provided will help you in this case, since the START command just makes sure a command will be executed in the background. I think there is a `start_service.cmd` file, maybe use that and then call `stop_service.cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in Talend by ***tSystem*** Component where you can write these command and execute the command by running the talend jobs.
If your Job server or Talend Studio is installed on Windows then.

```
START "" java -jar C:/H2/h2/bin/h2-1.4.195.jar -tcpAllowOthers
```

If Job Server or Talend Studio is installed on Linux then

```
java -jar C:/H2/h2/bin/h2-1.4.195.jar -tcpAllowOthers &
```