# Rollback transactions after each Cucumber scenarios with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, cucumber, h2

I'm using the BDD testing framework Cucumber with Spring Boot 2.5.
I want to rollback transactions or reset my database after each Cucumber scenarios. I'm using an H2 database, populate by dynamically generated data.
I tried @Transactional, but it doesn't work and @DirtiesContext is to slow.

Comment: How are you accessing the database (Jpa/Hibernate/JdbcTemplate/...)?

Comment: Spring Data JPA

Comment: What about embedded db? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205126/starting-an-h2-database-server-from-maven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the `PlatformTransactionManager` to start a transaction before each scenario and to roll it back after. This is essentially what `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` does when a JUnit test class annotated with `@Transactional` is executed.

In Cucumber you would do this using `@Before` and `@After` hooks. And because you may not want do this for every scenario you can choose to make the hooks conditional so that they only execute when a scenario is tagged in the right way.

For example:

```
@txn
Feature: Search

  Background:
    Given there is a user

  Scenario: Find messages by content
    Given a User has posted the following messages:
      | content            |
      | I am making dinner |
      | I just woke up     |
      | I am going to work |
    When I search for "I am"
    Then the results content should be:
      | I am making dinner |
      | I am going to work |
```

```java
public class SpringTransactionHooks implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Before(value = "@txn", order = 100)
    public void startTransaction() {
        transactionStatus = beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
                .getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
    }
    
    @After(value = "@txn", order = 100)
    public void rollBackTransaction() {
        beanFactory.getBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
                .rollback(transactionStatus);
    }

}
```

From:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/examples/spring-java-junit5

Comment: I did it that way, while in the service annotated method with @Transactional new TransactionStatus gets created and commited. I am debugging it through `TransactionAspectSupport` class.

Comment: Works not for me... Transaction hook is executed, but rollback is not performed. Using Spring 2.7, JUnit 5, Cucumber 7.15.0, with an embedded H2 db